# Iterating through objects of arrays in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, loops

I have following data structure (number of objects is not limited to just five):

```
Object {name: "objectName}, data: Array}
Object {name: "objectName}, data: Array}
Object {name: "objectName}, data: Array}
Object {name: "objectName}, data: Array}
Object {name: "objectName}, data: Array}
```

`data` property is a multidimensional `Array` filled with objects (their number is not limited too) with following structure:

```
[
    {
        property: "value",
        property2: "value"
    },
    {
        property: "value",
        property2: "value"
    }
]
```

Here I'm having a trouble with accessing these objects and their values I wanna display.
Here's what I'm using:

```
Object.keys(this.state.items).map((k, index) => <li key={index}>{ `${k}: ${this.state.items[k]}` }</li>
```

It gives me following output:

```
name: propertyName
data: [object Object],[object Object], [n, n]
```

where `n` represents the fact that there's unlimited number of objects.
So how can I correctly iterate through this structure to eventually have an accsess to `object` values? I'd like to display it as

```
{item.property}
```

and so on. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly do you want to display? Only the `property` key and it's value or every key from each object in `data` array?

Comment: @Kinduser I wanna display every value from every object in `data` array

Comment: The variable (array) you provided is invalid. Provide a proper one.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the items and then iterate over the data for each item.

```
  class App extends React.Component {
      state = {
        items: [
          {
            id: 1,
            name: 'name 1',
            data: [
              { id: 1, property: 'Property 1' },
              { id: 2, property: 'Property 2' }
            ],
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            name: 'name 2',
            data: [
              { id: 1, property: 'Property 3' },
              { id: 2, property: 'Property 4' }
            ],
          }
        ]
      }
      render() {
        return (
          <ul>
            {this.state.items.map((row) => {
              return (
                <li key={row.id}>
                  <div>{row.name}</div>
                  <ul>
                    {row.data.map(innerRow => {
                      return <li key={innerRow.id}>{innerRow.property}</li>
                    })}
                  </ul>
                </li>
              )
            })}
          </ul>
        )
      }
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work for me, this code gives me `.map is not a function` so I supposse that `this.state.items`  gives me a straight object so that's why I used `Object.keys`. I mentioned my current code and its output, but still can't find a way to access inner array and its object :(